# Angularjs selectors migration to Angular 6

Tags: angularjs, angular, css-selectors, angular-upgrade

Currently in the less there is:

```
.ng-click-active,
    [ng-click]:active {
        background: lightgreen;
    }
```

Which is left from our project migration to the new angular (currently 6.1). How can i achieve the same behavior in it? Is there a way without writing some attribute directives that attach to mousedown/touchstart + mouseup/touchend/touchcancel  and  add/remove class?

Comment: sad but does not work :s

Comment: I don't think you're going to find an equivalent to this in Angular. You might have to just apply the CSS to `button:active` and/or `a:active`.